# Read the grammar box and check your answer. Should I put a comma?

Tags: conjunctions, punctuation

I am proofreading, and I found this sentence:

> ***Read the passage and answer the questions below.***

I believe that we need to put a comma before 'and' since there are two independent clauses.

Thus, it will be:

> ***Read the passage[,] and answer the questions below.***

Am I correct?

Comment: Please do not use horizontal lines to offset example sentences. Use a quote box instead. See our [ELL Contributor's Guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners/4799#4799) for more formatting tips. Also, do not add "Thanks" to the end of your question. It is considered clutter on this site, and it takes up time for other members to tidy it up. See [this page](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour), and note: _Ask questions, get answers, no distractions. This site is not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat._

Answer (score 2):

No, not necessarily.
A comma is used when listing **multiple** things.
For example, I ate my meals, took a shower, and played the game yesterday.

When listing only two things, only "and" is enough (although a comma can be used too).
For example, I ate my meals and played the game yesterday.

Comment: worth noting the ***, and*** is an oxford comma

Answer (score -1):

You could also write any of these:

1) Read the passage, answer the questions below.
2) Read the passage and answer the question below.
3) Read the passage then answer the question below.
4) Read the passage, then answer the question below.

And plenty more, I am sure.

'then' is logically equal to 'and'.
'and' is logically equal to a comma.

Comment: Then is NOT logically equal to and. Sometimes, it can be replaced, but that does not make it equal

Comment: 'Logically' equal, NOT equal. All instances of 'then' can be replaced with 'and'.

Comment: Equality is 2 sided. All instances of 'then' can be replaced with 'and' but not vice versa.